# Como liberar porta 80 para o Apache?

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

Estou usando EasyPHP, e quando vou iniciar, o Apache exibe um erro dizendo que a porta 80 já está em uso.

[image]

Como faço para liberar essa porta 80?

Acabei de verificar as portas e vi que tem um `inetinfo.exe` (Internet Information Services) ocupando essa porta. Como consigo remove-lo?

Estou usando Windows XP e este `inetinfo.exe` está em:

> C:WINDOWS\system32\inetinfo.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está rodando o [IIS](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eaa94a72-77b1-4b4e-abad-314d6b49ba5c.mspx?mfr=true), para interrompe-lo, no `cmd.exe` faça:

```
net stop w3svc
```

Isso desativará o [Serviço de Publicação da World Wide Web](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/930905).

[Mais informações](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/185382)

Feito isto, provavelmente a porta *80* estará livre para uso.

Answer (score 1):

Vê se o Skype ta aberto, e outros programas que usam a porta 80.

A maioria das vezes que dá um erro de porta 80 já em uso, é o Skype que tá aberto.

Comment: Não, to usando esse PC sem internet,

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria você alterar a porta do `EasyPHP`, pois alguns outros programas usam a porta 80 por padrão.

Para alterar a Porta Padrão do EasyPHP:

1 - Clique no ícone do EasyPHP

2 - Vá até **Configuration** e clique em **Apache**

3 - Procure por **Listen 127.0.0.1:80**

4 - Altere **80** por **8080**

5 - Reinicie o EasyPHP

Sempre que for acessar agora, acesse `http://localhost:8080` ou `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: Deu certo, valeu.